# King and three knights vs king․

Tags: endgame, pawn-promotion, famous-games, knight-endgame

Is there any recorded official game in history where the king and three knights play against the lone king in the endgame?
I know it can be a very rare case where in practice both knights stay until the end of the game and the other knight appears from the pawn promotion.

Comment: I searched ChessBase Mega Database 2024. I found 12 games where a king and three knights play against a lone king. However, most games were from blitz tournaments and all games appeared to be jokes. The player who promoted to a third knight could have easily won the game some other way.

Comment: It can be forced in a study, I bet, with not that much material on the board, so a real game running into the same position is thinkable.